# Data from array is not showing up in the pickerView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, nsarray, uipickerview

I am trying to do Single-Component Picker example Beginning iOS 6 Development Book, almost every thing works fine but Data from array is not showing up in the pickerView
Please Help

Here is my .h file

```
<UIPickerViewDataSource , UIPickerViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIPickerView *singlePicker;
    NSArray *chaNames;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *singlePicker;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *chaNames;



- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;


@end
```

And here is .m file

```
#import "SSPSingleComponentViewController.h"

@interface SSPSingleComponentViewController ()

@end

@implementation SSPSingleComponentViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.chaNames = @[@"Luke",@"Leia",@"Han",@"Chewbacca",@"Artoo", @"Threepio",@"lando"];
}



- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

    NSInteger row = [self.singlePicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    NSString *selected = self.chaNames[row];
    NSString *title = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"You slected %@", selected];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"OutPut is : " message:title delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [alert show];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [self.chaNames count];
}
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
            titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
           forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return[self.chaNames objectAtIndex:row];
}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

Please Help
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are the picker view's data source and delegate methods being called at all? Make sure you setup the picker view's `dataSource` and `delegate` properties.

Comment: Hi,

I setup the picker view's dataSource and delegate properties but still not working

Comment: As I asked the first time, are the data source and delegate method being called at all? Set a breakpoint in `numberOfComponentsInPickerView` or add an `NSLog`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to alloc your NSArray object as follows:

```
self.chaNames = [NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Luke",@"Leia",@"Han",@"Chewbacca",@"Artoo", @"Threepio",@"lando"];
```

Edit:

you also need to set singlePicker.datasource = self; and singlePicker.delegate = self; within viewDidLoad or hook it up correctly with IB (both the delegate and datasource)

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    self.chaNames = [NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Luke",@"Leia",@"Han",@"Chewbacca",@"Artoo", @"Threepio",@"lando"];
}
```

Comment: if your connecting via interface builder make sure you connect the datasource and delegate as well. Also make sure both that the datasource and delegate are mentioned in the .h file

Comment: in viewDidLoad you also need to set singlePicker.datasource = self; and singlePicker.delegate = self;

Comment: you can mark this answer as 'the answer' to close your post ;)

Comment: @BarryK88 If the `dataSource` and `delegate` are setup properly in IB, there is no need to also set them in `viewDidLoad`.